# Using WScript.Arguments() in oCN.Execute

Tags: vbscript

What is the correct method to use `WScript.Arguments()` within `oCN.Execute`?

I am using the below but it is throwing error messages.

`oCN.Execute("SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM WScript.Arguments(0)_TABLE.DBF")`

Answer (score 2):

VBScript does no variable interpolation at all. You need to use concatenation (or something more elaborate (Join, Replace, ...). Assuming the argument(s) are validated:

```
Set oRS = oCN.Execute("SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM " & WScript.Arguments(0) & "_TABLE.DBF")
```